# C String prints junk characters

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char a[]="shevchenko ac milan";
printf("%s",&a);
}
```

This is prints "shevchenko ac milan"

```
but 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char a[]="shevchenko ac milan";
printf("%s",&a+1);
}
```

Why does this print junk characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&a` is of type *pointer to a `char[20]`*.

When you do `&a+1` you'll go to the next `char[20]` item in memory, thus you'll go after `a`.

You should instead have a `char*`: by summing 1 to it you'll go to the next `char`.

To obtain a `char*` you can just use `a` (it decays in a `char*` by doing this), and thus `a+1` to go the next char.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass the address of a (`&a`) - in C a string is an array of `char`s, so `a` is already an address. Try:

```
char a[]="shevchenko ac milan"; printf("%s", a);
```

and

```
char a[]="shevchenko ac milan"; printf("%s", a+1);
```

Comment: yes but i want to know why in the second case junk characters get printed

Comment: should i be expecting hevchenko ac milan

Comment: @karthik A: Some of the other answers explain why-- because "&a" is a pointer to a 20-character array, and it will jump. You're passing a `char **` type (double pointer) to `printf`, and you shouldn't-- you should pass a `char *`, which `a` is. So this answer is correct for helping you FIX it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you say &a + 1 .This would make the pointer reach one location ahead of the end of string.**This is the pointers basic operation**.You could check this for an integer array also.

For e.g.

`int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};`

`printf("%d",&a+1);` would always print garbage value.

That is it would now ***going to point to next 1D array*** which is actually not there.Thus garbage value gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

When you increment the "address that points to an address", you get an unassigned value.  fbrereto is right, you only need to pass a for the pointer to the first position, and a+1 to point to the second position in the array.